# Install or run the tool on a machine where users dont have the admin rights

Tags: c#, installation

I have developed a C# windows form application. I want it to install and run it on a machine. The current user logged in to this machine dont have any admin rights. He is the normal user and can not provide the admin rights. The issue with the normal user is that I can not install the tool on the machine. I have also tried to run the installer using the run as admin as well as by disabling the UAC settings. But it results in the same.  How can I resolve this issue? Do I need to do any changes in the code of tool? Please provide the solution for it.

Comment: Is there anything in your tool that actually needs installation? Why not just provide a simple zip file for xcopy deployment?

Comment: What is the tool actually doing? Is it going to operate functions that require admin privileges or is that you cant install the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get NSIS to install and execute files from a temp directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119461/how-can-i-get-nsis-to-install-and-execute-files-from-a-temp-directory)